# How to use grep match as a variable (and not whole line)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is the sample file

```
[user@linux]$ cat DeviceA
DeviceA#sh ver
Cisco IOS Software, 1841 Software (C1841-ADVSECURITYK9-M), Version 15.1(4)M10, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
[user@linux]$
```

`Version 15.1(4)M10` will be highligted

```
[user@linux]$ egrep --color=auto 'Version (15.1\(4\)M7|15.1\(4\)M10|15.2\(1\)T4)' DeviceA
Cisco IOS Software, 1841 Software (C1841-ADVSECURITYK9-M), Version 15.1(4)M10, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
[user@linux]$
```

Using grep output as variable `var`

```
[user@linux]$ var=$(egrep --color=auto 'Version (15.1\(4\)M7|15.1\(4\)M10|15.2\(1\)T4)' DeviceA)
[user@linux]$
```

Print variable `var`

```
[user@linux]$ echo $var
Cisco IOS Software, 1841 Software (C1841-ADVSECURITYK9-M), Version 15.1(4)M10, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
[user@linux]$
```

Instead of getting the whole line as `var`, can I just get `Version 15.1(4)M10` when executing `echo $var`?

**Desired Output**

```
[user@linux]$ echo $var
Version 15.1(4)M10
[user@linux]$
```

Comment: See the [`grep (1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) and the `-o` option. You should also start using Shellcheck. It will tell you to use `grep -E` instead of `egrep`. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: It's good to accept answers to your existing questions first. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, I appreciate your answer. Unfortunately I don't really understand it. 

At the moment, I'm trying to write another code to solve the same problem.

Till then, I'll wait for better answer, easy to understand, and then I'll accept it. Btw, I've already accepted the answer for this question which is `fgrep -o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Jww, this can easily be achieved using the `-o` flag:

Commandline:

```
fgrep -o "Version 15.1(4)M10" testtttt.txt, or, for introducing variable handling:
echo $(fgrep -o "Version 15.1(4)M10" testtttt.txt)
```

In a script, you might do something like (not tested):

```
var=$(fgrep -o "Version 15.1(4)M10" testtttt.txt)
echo $var
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
tmp="${var%,*}"           # remove last part after ,
echo "${tmp##*,}"         # print last part after ,
```